# Binding an observable collection attribute to a label in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have the following observable collection called SalesOrderCollection

```
   private static ObservableCollection<SalesOrder> _salesOrderCollection = new ObservableCollection<SalesOrder>();

 public static ObservableCollection<SalesOrder> SalesOrderCollection
        {
            get { return _salesOrderCollection; }
            set
            {
                _salesOrderCollection  = value;
            }
        }
```

I am assigning values like this:

```
SalesOrder order = new SalesOrder();
            order.ItemSubTotal = 234;
            order.TotalTaxes = 12;
            order.TOTAL = 12345;

            SalesOrderCollection.Add(order);
```

In the view, I am setting it like this to the label:

```
 <Label Content="{Binding Path=TOTAL, UpdateSourceTrigger =PropertyChanged}"/>
```

However the label is empty. Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: AFAIK ObservableCollection has no property named **TOTAL**

Comment: My observable collection does have a property named TOTAL because it contains LineItem objects which contains the attributes like LineItemTotal and TOTAL

Comment: Something like this    private static ObservableCollection<LineItem> Items = new ObservableCollection<LineItem>();

Comment: No, the ObservableCollection<T> does **NOT** have a property named **TOTAL**. The item inside that collection maybe have but that is a different story. Check the docs to proove that https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ok, so just like I binded the ObservableCollection to the data grid, how do I do the same to the label? I can't attach ItemsSource property to the label just like I did to the DataGrid.

Comment: @bangbang You need to make clear to which item of the collection you want to bind. There are many, but a single Label can only bind to one of them, for example the selected one.

Comment: Please check my question again. I got what you were saying. I changed my logic altogether and now there is only one item in the observable.

Comment: Then why is there a collection property at all? Add a property of type SalesOrder to your view model.

Comment: Note also that setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is pointless. It has no effect in a OneWay Binding.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are binding incorrectly - the label should not be bound to a specific item in a collection. Instead you should use a list control to show the contents of the ObesrvableCollection, then bind the selected item in the list control to a property on the viewmodel. Then the label should also be bound to the same property which contains the selected object.

If you insist on doing indexed binding to a specific item in the ObservableCollection then this syntax should do it for you:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=SalesOrderCollection[0].TOTAL}"/>
```

[Here](http://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Silverlight-WPF-Binding-to-a-specific-item-in-a-collection) is an example.
Just another pointer: I'm not sure why you've made your `SalesOrderCollection` property static - this looks like the start of some potentially smelly code.